# Why does my ASP.NET MVC HTML helper output an XHTML checkbox that isn't valid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, xhtml

For some reason an HTML helper is outputting this HTML which doesn't validate.

The validator tells me:

> There is no attribute "Length"

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("Medicamentos", Model.Medicamentos) %>
```

is outputting

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Medicamentos" id="Medicamentos" checked="checked" length="4">
```

Comment: Also, do you have data annotations on your model?

Comment: I doubt it is outputting that directly. As far as I recall, your HtmlHelper call would, by default, render a checkbox without the checked="checked" attribute, and I suspect the length="4" is coming from somewhere else too. You might want to double check your code.

Comment: Many of the validity problems in ASP.NET can be solved by using `clientTarget` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx) to turn off the ridiculous browser-sniffing code the web controls use by default. I don't know about *this* one, as `length` is a bizarre, meaningless attribute that has never existed on `<input>` on any browser I've ever heard of, but it might be worth a go.

Comment: @bobince, @chris -- the problem is that it is matching a method signature that considers the model property to be the html attributes for the element.  I suspect there's a boolean property on the (complex) model property that needs to be directly addressed instead -- either checked or value.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that it's matching the signature that takes a string and an object since I don't know what `Model.Medicamentos` is.  In that case it takes the properties of the object and turns them into attributes on the element.  I suspect that you simply want to use the `Checked` attribute on the Model property specified as the default value of the checkbox, i.e.,

```
<%= Html.CheckBox( "Medicamentos", Model.Medicamentos.Checked ) %>
```

In, which case, assuming that `Checked` is boolean it will match the correct method signature on the helper extension.

Comment: Ah! Yes, the overload causing the wrong CheckBox method to happen — good guess, I think you're right. (Those reflection-based `Object` arguments are dangerous!)